# Change xy ticks values when ploting a matrix _ matplotlib

Tags: python, matrix

I am given a 2D Matrix of certain dimension (a,b) with real entries between -1.0 and +1.0. I am trying to visualize each cell value on a scale (see attached figure).

The issue that I am running into is not being able to change the values of the x and y axis.
In particular, given the code I'm using (see below) the x and y axis range from 0 to 16, however I am trying to assign different values for the axis, say -1.0 to 3.0 in steps of 0.25. Any suggestions for how I can do that?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,10))

plt.imshow(M, cmap = plt.cm.seismic, vmin=-1, vmax=1)

plt.xticks(np.arange(0,17,1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,17,1))

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="1.5%", pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(cax=cax)
```

[Plotting a 17x17 Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPn3e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [set_xticklabels](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) and [set_yticklabels](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html)

```
ax.set_xticklabels(np.linspace(-1,3,17))
ax.set_yticklabels(np.linspace(-1,3,17))
```